# Pandas: how to deal with data associated with higher levels of hierarchical index?

Tags: python, pandas, multilevel-analysis

I have a Pandas dataframe similar to (but much larger than) :

```
                         dob name                     x                     y
subject_code datapoint                                                       
subject1     0          2000  foo    1.0130617046645218   -0.9197554534168588
             1          2000  foo    1.6268826597606547    0.9235889343439213
             2          2000  foo  -0.27934495719523383   -0.7649336229271105
subject2     3          1980  bar     0.799986663648364   0.17376727917253385
             4          1980  bar   0.05939596855122923    1.6401662246395807
             5          1980  bar   -0.6496807099005506   -0.9591735410133281
             6          1980  bar   -0.6953680580655669  -0.15390936342856965
```

Which I have read in from a flat csv file where all of the subject-level attributes (like `subject_code`,`dob`and `name` here) are repeated for every column, using the command `df = pd.read_csv(PATH, index_col=["subject_code", "datapoint"])`.

Currently the dob and name are repeated in every column, which seems to be bad practice. My questions are twofold:

1. Is there a way to associate the columns `dob` and `name` with the higher level index `subject_code`, such that they are in the same table but not repeated?
2. What's the best way to pull out the `subject_code`, `dob` and `name` into a separate, smaller table?

With respect to (2), I'm currently this far:

```
subject_cols = df.groupby("subject_code")\
                 .nunique()\
                 .max() == 1

subject_cols = subject_cols.index[subject_cols]
```

with `df[subject_cols]` giving:

```
                         dob name
subject_code datapoint           
subject1     0          2000  foo
             1          2000  foo
             2          2000  foo
subject2     3          1980  bar
             4          1980  bar
```

Comment: The toy example can be generated with:

Comment: ```part_data = np.array([[2000, "foo"]]*3 + [[1980, "bar"]]*4);

data = np.concatenate((part_data, np.random.randn(7, 2)), axis=1);

index = [["subject1"]*3 +["subject2"]*4, np.arange(7)];
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index, names=["subject_code", "datapoint"]);

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=["dob", "name", "x", "y"])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following dataframe I get from running your toy example:

```py
print(df)
# Output
                         dob name                     x                     y
subject_code datapoint
subject1     0          2000  foo     0.513162983337374  0.007833678673477415
             1          2000  foo    1.5251357488726798   -0.2107782114549924
             2          2000  foo    -1.213546898092921   -0.9955113729604301
subject2     3          1980  bar  -0.19001014005197553    -0.863345548112192
             4          1980  bar   -0.7446186914220339    -0.388115467600475
             5          1980  bar  -0.04464842762041622   0.08245820701430223
             6          1980  bar    0.9529697829289847   -0.7613603252199205
```

You can accomplish the first task using Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```py
df = df.reset_index().groupby(["subject_code", "dob", "name", "datapoint"]).agg(list)

for col in ["x", "y"]:
    df = df.explode(col)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
                                                     x                     y
subject_code dob  name datapoint
subject1     2000 foo  0             0.513162983337374  0.007833678673477415
                       1            1.5251357488726798   -0.2107782114549924
                       2            -1.213546898092921   -0.9955113729604301
subject2     1980 bar  3          -0.19001014005197553    -0.863345548112192
                       4           -0.7446186914220339    -0.388115467600475
                       5          -0.04464842762041622   0.08245820701430223
                       6            0.9529697829289847   -0.7613603252199205
```

And the second task with Pandas [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```py
other_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    df.reset_index(level=3).index, columns=df.reset_index(level=3).index.names
).drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
```

```py
print(other_df)
# Output
  subject_code   dob name
0     subject1  2000  foo
1     subject2  1980  bar
```